# Why the item of recyclerview does not at the center in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing in `recycleView` for Android, and I try to center the item in recycle like the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>



        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/test"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And the `layout` of item is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/blue">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="123"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And use the linearlayout like the following:

```
        val adapter = ShowAdapter(viewModel)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.recycleview.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.recycleview.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

But it show like the following:
[image]

the Button did not at the center, did I missing something?
Thanks ion advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a gravity layout in your `linearlayout`

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" 
        //here it is
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: You have two linearlayouts try to add gravity to the first one as the parent of recycleview

Comment: Please see your closing tag upon checking the missing is the `</recycleView>`?

Answer (score 0):

Change gravity to your component, you have two ways to do it :

1) Change parent gravity (here in LinearLayout) by using `android:gravity="center"`
Note this : all your children will be affected and centered

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" 
        //here it is
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

2) Change component level gravity (here button) by using `android:layout_gravity="center"`
Note this : only your button will be affected by this new gravity

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="123"/>
```

Also, I see you are using androidx. Better for you to use `MaterialButton` instead of `Button`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="123"/>
```

Please check out this [link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for that much complexity, use a `FrameLayout` as it is more performant.

```xml
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="123" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If for some reason your item layout only has one button you can even remove the `FrameLayout` and use the `MaterialButton` directly as the root element.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="123" />
```

The important attribute is the `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

If you do switch to the `LinearLayout` then you can change the root's `android:gravity` property:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:background="@color/blue"> <!-- background color just to show the cell height -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: example]

On this last case, it is important to keep the width to wrap_content (if vertical, height otherwise).

Comment: @Wun have you checked this solution?

Answer (score 0):

use this layout it will display button in center of item

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="123"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code I tested it and it is working fine

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

For adapter item

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="123"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter class

```
public class TestAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context mContext;
    private List<String> orderList;


    public TestAdapter(List<String> orders,
                       Context context) {
        this.orderList = orders;
        this.mContext = context;

        try {
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString()
                    + " must implement OnAccountPermissionChanged");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TestAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        return new TestAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        String t = orderList.get(i);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(t);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderList == null ? 0 : orderList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public Button textView;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);


        }
    }


}
```

Activity code

```
 recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        List<String> test=new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("aa");
        test.add("aa");
        test.add("aa");
        test.add("aa");
        TestAdapter adapter=new TestAdapter(test,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please check my answer again, I shared full code and it is working fine with me